# How to add/change an Android Studio toolbar icon to an action?

Tags: android-studio, toolbar

In Android Studio (2.2.2) when I add a new action to the Main toolbar, there is an option to "Edit Action icon..." but when I select a png file from the file system, Android Studio complains with "Icon is too big to appear in menu".

What are the image characteristics that must complain the file in order to use it as an Android Studio toolbar icon?

I have tried with all the resolutions provided by this url as png 24dp:
https://material.io/icons/#ic_aspect_ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with a 18x18 32 bits PNG image